# Django Wagtail Jinja2 include_block tag not passing variables

Tags: django, wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

I have the following very simple statement to render blocks in wagtail.

```
{% for block in blocks %}
    {% include_block block %}
{% endfor %}
```

The for loop works and iterates over the blocks as does the template tag include_block. The variable 'block' however is not accessible in the template executed by include_block.

```
{% set background_image = block.background_image.image %}
```

The above statement called in the template called by include_block throws the following error.

```
'block' is undefined
```

This does not really make sense since the documentation for Wagtail's include_block states that variables get passed down into the called template.

http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.9/advanced_topics/jinja2.html#include-block

I have the following statement in order to explicitly pass in variables but it still does not work,

```
 {% include_block block with context %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed surprising that `block` doesn't get passed down and might constitute a bug (edit: see comments below for further discussion on that matter)

That being said, in a block template, the block value is accessible as the variable `value` (see 6th paragraph of the [StreamField template rendering](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.9/topics/streamfield.html#template-rendering) section).

Comment: Thank you! I was confused by that in the docs. I thought that the value would have been a part of a block. It gets a little confusing with Stream blocks having struct blocks and those having blocks...

Comment: Looking a bit further into the possible bug, the [documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#import-context-behavior) state that with Jinja `2.0`, "the context that was passed to the included template did not include variables defined in the template". This was presumably fixed in `2.1`. Can you confirm which version of Jinja you have installed? I'll look at filing a bug if needed to be.

Comment: Thank you. I am using Jinja 2.9. This is why I was so perplexed.